# SQLAlchemy & dynamically setting Table column values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying to do this:

```
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(bind=engine, schema='schema')
Mapper(Table, meta.tables['schema.table'])

t = Table("schema.table", meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
map = {'Col1': 'full_local_col1_name', 'Col2': 'full_local_col2_name'}

for remote, local in map.items():
    t.set(local, values[remote])
```

The idea being that `values` is a `Dictionary` object obtained from another service, and I am mapping the column names to my local table.

How can I accomplish this? SQLAlchemy's `Table` class has no `set` method.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do.. Are you trying to insert, update,  alter or something totally different? You can do this for insert.

```
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(bind=engine, schema='schema')
Mapper(Table, meta.tables['schema.table'])

t = Table("schema.table", meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
map = {'Col1': 'full_local_col1_name', 'Col2': 'full_local_col2_name'}

t.insert().values(**{local: values[remote] for remote, local in map.items()})
```